# Finding/Setting the height of the string of Java.awt drawString

Tags: java

So for a tower defense game I am developing, I want to have a sprite with text in it that the towers are defending. However the text inside this sprite needs to change based on the damage it has received. I am a little bit pedantic and need the exact X and Y to draw the string at in order for it to be centered in the image.

How do I find the height of the String so that I can adjust the Y element of the drawn string accordingly?

```
    g.setColor(new Color(Integer.parseInt(tObj[0].toString())));
    g.drawString(String.format("Wave: %d", getWave()), 5, 460);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume 2D rectangle, for which top left corner is at `point.x,point.y` coords and has `width` width and `height` height.
When I needed to draw a String into the center of that rectangle, I used this.

```
    String text = "Centered Text";
    FontMetrics fontMetrics = graphics.getFontMetrics();
    Rectangle2D rect = fontMetrics.getStringBounds(text, graphics);
    int x = point.x + (width - (int) rect.getWidth()) / 2;
    int y = point.y + (height - (int) rect.getHeight()) / 2 + fontMetrics.getAscent();
    graphics.drawString(text, x, y);
```